# How to set the minimum height of a <div> box in Internet Explorer 8?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

The below CSS code that uses the `min-height` property applied to a `<div>` box is not working properly in Internet Explorer 8. An example is given below.

```
 .myDiv
{
    min-height:200px;
    height:auto !important;
    height:200px;

}
```

How can I set the minimum height of the `<div>` box in a way that works in Internet Explorer 8?

Comment: this should be working

Comment: min-height supported from IE7

Comment: why are you specifying `height` twice?

Comment: see http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/cross-browser-min-height/

Comment: Just a thought, but perhaps in IE8 second `height` takes over and is always set to 200?

Comment: @YuriyGalanter to assure property always gets applied you have to add !important property, that's why there is `height` twice.

Comment: `height:auto !important` is gonna "win" as it has a _much_ higher specificity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code should be working as it is supported to be threatened like `min-height`.

You can try adding following property to your style

```
<!--[if IE]>
<style type="text/css">
    .myDiv { 
      height:expression(this.scrollHeight < 200 ? "200px" : "auto");
    }
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

If it still does not work then you probably have got some issues with other elements and or nesting your .myDiv properly.